# std::vector memory management

Tags: c++, vector

As far as I know, `std::vector` reserves some memory for the data it will contain, and if that memory is full it copies all the data to a new larger block of memory.

for example if the vector contains 2 elements the memory is like this :

```
DD--XX-----                  D for vector's data, - for empty, X for other data
```

if I add two elements it will become like this :

`DDDDXX-----`

but if I try to add another element the vector will copy all the elements and free the previous memory :

`----XXDDDDD`

Am I right ??

Now I don't want the vector to copy the members to an other block of memory, so I want to know when he is doing this. Is it possible ? using an insertion function that throws an exception when this happens for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I right ??

Kinda.

Your diagram makes it look like vectors reallocate when failure to do so would lead to them running into other allocated memory. That's not true. Vectors reallocate when they run out of memory that *they* allocated. It could be this

```
DD--------
DDD-------
------DDDD
```

even without any `X`.

The key here is the pre-allocation that vectors perform. Let's say your vector's capacity is 4:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.reserve(4);
v.push_back(999);
v.push_back(998);
v.push_back(997);
v.push_back(996);
```

This might lead to:

```
-------XX---------
PPPP---XX---------  set capacity
DPPP---XX---------  add element
DDPP---XX---------  add element
DDDP---XX---------  add element
DDDD---XX---------  add element
DDDD---XX--PPPPPPP  increase capacity; requires new allocation...
DDDD---XX--DDDDPPP  ... and copying of data ...
-------XX--DDDDPPP  ... and de-allocation of the original memory
```

And so forth.

> Now I don't want the vector to copy the members to an other block of memory, so I want to know when he is doing this. Is it possible ? using an insertion function that throws an exception when this happens for example

Not really, but you can simply compare `myVector.size()` against `myVector.capacity()` and throw an exception yourself, instead of `push`ing`_back`, when the two are equal. This will prevent the vector itself from handling this case by reallocating and copying.

It kind of sounds like you want vector to grow *in-place* as much as it can, then throw when it runs out of space in process memory. But, as far as I'm aware, there's no OS-level support for that and certainly nothing that C++ has access to. (Note that even `realloc` may also move data.) You could invent a new kind of computer to do it. Writing a pool allocator could get you this, in theory, but *why*? That's an awful lot of work and surprising semantics for — as far as I can tell — basically no benefit whatsoever.

Comment: hmm this explains a lot of things, but can't vector be smarter ? Do I need to implement a new allocator ?

Comment: @OthmanBenchekroun: It's perfectly smart. What would make it "smarter" in your book? Why do you think you need this? The fact that it re-allocates and copies for you _is_ its smartness; you seem to be saying the opposite.

Comment: Look at my comments about Kiril's answers

Comment: @Othman: I did and they made no sense. I'd revisit your requirements. Either you want runtime bounds or you don't; you can't have it both ways.

Comment: What I mean about smart is that It could have added new data after the previous one (when it's possible) without moving it

Comment: @OthmanBenchekroun: And where do you propose that data be stored? A magical land where no memory need ever be allocated before use?

Comment: Right after previous data ?

Comment: @OthmanBenchekroun: That is not how computers work. See my new final paragraph.

Comment: ok, I see, It may be a lot of work, but I think it can be very benefitial.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have understood the behavior of `std::vector` correctly.

You can watch `std::capacity` - it gives you the size of the capacity of the vector, meaning - how may elements the vector can hold before next reallocation. You can do something like

```
std::vector< type >::size_type remaining_places = v.capacity() - v.size();
```

You cannot fully prevent this, but you can use `std::vector::reserve` to change the capacity of the vector at any time.

Comment: I tried this code : https://ideone.com/DiI3di , and the capacity after I push one vector is always 1, why does vector allocate few memory, even if  the compiler can staticly see that I am doing another push back ?

Comment: @OthmanBenchekroun - yes, that's what you exactly explained in your question. Try adding `v.reserve( 10 );` after creating the vector and `push_back` 11 elements - you'll see that the reallocation is on the 11th push.

Comment: I don't know how many objects I will be pushing into the vector, so I can't reserve memory, But I definitely don't want it to copy the vector each time I am adding an object

Comment: @OthmanBenchekroun then don't use `std::vector`. You can check when the reallocation will happen, but you cannot prevent it. Think about `std::deque` or `std::list` or something else, if you don't want reallocations.

Comment: I can't use list or deque since I need contiguous data (as much as possible).

Comment: @OthmanBenchekroun - well.. this sounds impossible to me, unless I'm missing something. Think about this - you need a continuous memory, but you do not want reallocations. This means - allocate memory once and use it, until it gets full. And `reserve` does exactly this. There's no way to "extend" the memory, without reallocating. Of course, you can try some solution with `malloc`, `memmove`, etc. but you should be really careful with these. And they will still use reallocations, just without calling copy constructors.

Comment: How about, something like vector but that allocates the biggest block ofmemory possible at first, and only when this block is full, add the next elements to another block. That sounds like a list of vectors, but it must know when a vector can't have more elements before it create a new vector.

Comment: _"I don't know how many objects I will be pushing into the vector, so I can't reserve memory, But I definitely don't want it to copy the vector each time I am adding an object"_ That's a logical impossibility. Just think about it. Unless you allocated literally all memory on your computer.

Comment: That is not a logical impossibility, maybe impossible for the current computers, but I can imagine such smart vectors

Comment: A maximum available continuous section of memory is reserving and pre-allocating all available memory. Memory management does not allocate randomly, it attempts to reduce wasted space while preserving alignment, you must reserve space or dynamically relocate. A list of arrays or list of vectors would probably be most similar to the magical allocation that you describe, but this still needs to reserve the size of each array or vector in the list. And with the list of vectors you need to fill more like an array so they do not grow beyond reserve and get copied. Use 8byte alignment

Answer (score 2):

The actual specification of std::vector is something like

```
template < class T, class Alloc = allocator<T> > class vector;
```

where `Alloc` is the type of an object that is delegated to in order to allocate raw memory.

If you want to intercept the resizing operations performed by a vector, provide an appropriately tailored allocator.   Your tailored allocator (a class, possibly templated) will need to permit the first operation that reserves or sets size, but throws an exception on subsequent resizing attempts.     Look up the templated `std::allocator` (and, in C++``, `std::allocator_traits`) for a specification of the interface that your tailored allocator must support.

Comment: +1! I've never used these yet. I don't think this is a good solution, but it IS one, allowed by the standard, so I'm giving you my upvote.

Comment: The OP asked for a solution that would throw an exception on trying to insert, and prevent the resize.   Using `reserve()` and watching `capacity()` doesn't achieve that.

Comment: I am not good enough to implement an `allocator` to try this solution, but I see how this can solve my issue, thanks

Comment: @Peter - instead of changing the allocator just to thrown an exception on `push_back`, OP can check the `size` and the `capacity` before each `push_back` to prevent reallocations. Anyway, I think this is impossible - OP needs continuous memory with unknown size, but does not want reallocations.

Comment: @Kiril:  The fact you've never used an allocator is not a reason for using a more error prone (in the sense of requiring a programmer to remember to do the check every time) approach.   Quite simply, requiring `size()` and `capacity()` to be checked before every operation that potentially resizes a vector is an opportunity to forget to do the check.

Comment: @Peter - I agree, but I wouldn't use an allocator for this, not because I've never used :) Anyway, I've upvoted you competitive answer, which means that I agree with the idea. I wouldn't use this approach for several reasons, but this doesn't make it bad one, not at all.

Answer (score 0):

It is specified that `std::vector` **shall** store the elements in *contiguous* memory. That means if you append more values than are contiguously available, it will allocate a larger contiguous block elsewhere, and move the values from the old block of memory to the new block. This is **correct behavior** and there is nothing you can, or should, do about it.

To specifically answer your question, the vector will be "full" when

```
vector.size() == vector.capacity()
```

A single `push_back` or `emplace_back` (etc) after this point will require another allocation elsewhere, and you will note that the value of `.capacity()` will increase.

Answer (score 0):

std::vector will manage at least enough memory to hold the objects in it.

If you add another object causing it to run out of space, it will grow automatically - this is by design and it cannot be prevented, predicted or detected.

If your objects are move-aware, they will be `std::move`d into place in the new memory, not copied.

All objects in the vector are contiguous - there are never any gaps (other than padding demanded by alignment requirements).

If you remove some items from the middle, the ones at the end are moved down so that the vector still contains contiguous items.

If you want to prevent the vector from growing beyond a certain size, you must code for it (wrap the vector in another class?)

You can pre-reserve space in the vector using `std::vector::reserve()`